# Fixing "index out of range" error within code

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm running a code in which I have a list of lists. I access random indices using the following (assume list1 is the list that contains the lists. Each list within list1 is of the same length, so I just equated list2 to one of the lists):

```
import numpy as np

x=np.random.randint(0, len(list1))
y=np.random.randint(1, len(list2))

print list1[x][y]
```

This is obviously just a rough approximate of what I've actually written, but it follows the same lines. For some reason, sometimes I get an "index out of range" error, which I have no idea why because the numpy `randint` module is **exclusive on the high end**. Why might that be?

In addition, is there any way to write a block of code that would try the x and y indices and see if it works and if there is an error involved, just pick two new random indices? Could a try-except block work for this?

**EDIT**

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
 ridx=np.random.randint(0,len(l_bg_2))
 ridy=np.random.randint(1,len(l_bg))
 print (ridx,ridy)
 while ((bg_dict.has_key((ridx, ridy))) or (ridy==0)):
     if bg_dict.has_key((ridx, ridy)):
         ridx=np.random.randint(0,len(l_bg_2))
         ridy=np.random.randint(1,len(l_bg))
         print (ridx, ridy)
     if ridy==0:
         ridy=np.random.randint(1,len(l_bg))
         print (ridx, ridy)
 bg_dict[(ridx, ridy)]=1
 p['bg'] = (l_bg_2[ridx])[ridy]
```

I had added in print statements to catch which indices gave index errors. The last time I ran the code, I got an index error for l_bg_2[ridx][ridy] at ridx=41, ridy=451. I then just ran a print statement to get l_bg_2[41][451] and it worked. I have no idea why this is happening and don't have any idea on how to get this fixed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My wild guess is that you're getting an index out of range error because the index is out of range. :^)  Stick some `print`s in there and find out which list isn't as long as you think it is.

Comment: I would like to see those lists.

Comment: What is `max(len(x) for x in lists1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `y` is set using the `len` of `list2` (whatever that is) and lower-bounded at 1. Therefore, if `list2` is longer than the list at `list1[x]` or `list1[x]` is empty, you will get this error.

**Edit**:
I just noticed the part of your question where you ask about catching this in try/except. Yes, `IndexError` is catchable, but you should try to debug your actual problem before implementing something like this. If you don't know *why* it is happening, just throwing a try/except block could create a huge performance bottleneck (depending on how likely the exception is) or even cause an infinite loop (if it is certain).